# How to center text with absoloute position

Tags: html, css

I have text I want to appear over an image when hovered, However I cant get the text to center with the overlay. The text is a div that fills that parent which is the image.

This is my css (I am using bulma)

```
function PlaylistTile(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <figure className="m-2">
        <Link
          className="has-text-dark playlist-container"
          to={`../tracklist/${props.playlistId}`}
        >
          <div className="playlist-name subtitle has-text-centered">
            {props.playlistName}
          </div>
          <img
            className="playlist-image is-128x128 p-1"
            src={props.img}
            alt="playlist-cover"
          ></img>
        </Link>
      </figure>
    </>
  );
}
```

```css
.playlist-image {
  display    : block;
  width      : 128px;
  height     : 128px;
  object-fit : cover;
  opacity    : 100%;
  transition : all 0.1s ease-in;
  }
.playlist-name {
  padding          : 32px;
  background-color : rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  position         : absolute;
  opacity          : 0%;
  transition       : all 0.16s ease-in;
  }
.playlist-name:hover {
  opacity          : 100%;
  background-color : rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
```

I've tried a few things, I just set padding for now.

Some work better than others, some totally break...
issue 1
[image]
issue 2
[image]

Comment: You should try your best to share a reproducible example. I can't copy what you've put here anywhere to see how things are working.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.playlist-container {
  position  : relative;
  width     : 128px;
  height    : 128px;
  }
.playlist-name {
  position  : absolute;
  left      : 50%;
  top       : 50%;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
```